# Shell script execution Sequence

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sequence

I want to write a shell script which

1. initiate a process which that gets data from a data base and and writes to a file (time to do this varies from 5 min - few hours)
2. Use the data in the generated file and do some calculations

What command can I use in shell to pause till my first process is complete before executing the second part as the second part should not start till writing to the file is complete?

Comment: Does the command for the first part return before it is finished (i.e. does it run in the background)? Because if it only returns when it is finished then you don't need to do anything for this. If it does run in the background then do you have some way of being able to know when it is finished?

Comment: Yes it returns before it is finished and tries to execute the second part while the writing to a file is not yet complete.

Comment: Does it signal completion somehow? How do you know when it is finished?

Comment: Currently I have no good method unless looking at the processes which are running. or do a tail -f on the file which is being written

Comment: I'm assuming you can't just get the process not to go to the background? That would be the simplest way obviously. But barring that you *need* some way of being able to tell when it is done to be able to automate waiting for it to be done and figuring that out is the part we can't help you with.

Comment: Assuming I know the process would I be able to write a command to wait (in shell) till that process no longer is running then step into the second part?

Comment: You can sleep-loop and poll for a specifically named process (with `pgrep`), yes.

Comment: Thanks Etan Ill read on pgrep

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really need a command. Your shell should simply block until a spawned child terminates:

```
proc1
proc2 # <- will not be called until proc1 is done.
```

Things only get complicated when you do stuff like this:

```
proc1 &
proc2 # <- will start immediately after proc1 was launched
```

In that case you would have to `wait`, as Politank-Z points out:

```
proc1 &
wait
proc2
```

Which doesn't really make any sense.

---

*Edit: After your clarification*

You have to get the first process to communicate to you the process id of its child and check for that to finish. A crude attempt would be periodically checking for

```
ps x | grep -v grep | grep "$spawnedPID"
```

(Assuming the child processes is not the grep command itself)

Comment: You can't `wait` on non-child processes.

Comment: @EtanReisner: You are technically correct. The best kind of correct. I thought you were able to wait on grand-child processes. Editing ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`wait`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Builtins) command, but it depends on how part 1 is started.

Comment: This won't help if the process in part 1 is self-backgrounding or a daemon or some-such. It will if he manually backgrounds it but at that point it would be simpler to simply not do that (unless that's necessary for some unspecified part of this task).

Comment: @EtanReisner: OP asks about `till my first process is complete`. If  you self-background, you are technically done.